# Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, jvm

I've tried looking at similar ones and no solution has worked. I've previously run apps without a problem but my new app suddenly started giving me problems. It always fails when I try to run it saying:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is what the console displayed:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual        Machine.","position":{},"original":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.","position":{},"original":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."}

AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.","position":{},"original":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.","position":{},"original":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.614 secs

AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.","position":{},"original":"Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.","position":{},"original":"Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."}
```

This app is very simple and I have not changed it much from the stock layout. It is designed only for lollipop and uses only stock features. Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a problem with *building* your app, not with running it - though of course you have to managed to build successfully at some point before you can run it.

Comment: @Rand, did you find any solution ? I am facing the same issue, I have 32 bit configuration, I guess this is the issue.

Comment: This bug is quite annoying and nothing seems to help -.-

Comment: Search your layout.xml and find `android:shadowRadius="4dp" `  and delete it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It must have been a problem with my Java install. I removed all traces of Java (C://program files/Java/jdk) and jre folders and reinstalled it from the [official page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and now it works fine.

Comment: How did you did that. Please provide more details

Comment: Go into the control panel and uninstall all versions of Java. Then reinstall the latest one.

Comment: didn't work for me..

Comment: You can try "JavaRa" to remove traces of Java. Not sure if it helps though.

Comment: In case you have multiple JDK's installed (for whatever reason), make sure studio is using the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30631386/1544046

Answer (score 56):

Had the same error encountered which was due to conflicting drawable resources.  I did a clean project and the error was no longer encountered.

Comment: this worked for me. i had exit error 2

Comment: Wh00t, so simple! I had exit error 1.. Must have been some mixup between the team via git

Comment: Like SindriÞór I also had exit error 1 and this has solved it for me. Last hour was nothing but headaches, thanks @Kennth !

Comment: @Kenneth not working..!

Comment: this not works for me

Answer (score 16):

After a lot of surfing, i found out the problem is GC overhead (out of memory). By adding below code to my build.gradle saved my day.

```
android {

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }

}
```

reference - [ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277193/processexception-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception-finished-with-non-ze)

Comment: What's `g`? Gigabyte?

Comment: @Subby It is just an option to specify the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) for dex operation. ref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750404/android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g

Comment: `DexOptions.incremental` is obsolete and will be removed at the end of 2018

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you can change your buildToolsVersion num.

this is my problem：

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\ProgramTools\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pioneers.recyclerviewitemanimation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I just change buildToolsVersion to buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" and the problem was solved.

Comment: That was my solution too, i just check an old project and compared build.gradle and set to the same value of buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Comment: worked for me.... :-) problem was when i created new project.

Answer (score 12):

**Problem RAM**. I had similar message in my Messages Gradle Build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal. 
ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Why:** I didn't have free RAM on my laptop with the OS windows 8.1.

**Solution:** I closed a few programs that I don't need. After that, I had more free RAM and my project was built in android studio.

Comment: yeah, before error it show a dialog " not enough momory... " i don't remember extract message

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the solution was to close Android Studio and kill the java processs, which was very big (1.2 GB). After this, my project runs normally (OS X Mount Lion, Android Studio 1.2.2, iMac Mid 2011 4GB Ram).

Comment: Hadn't even thought of this. Worked for me. Simply restarting AS (like 4 times) did nothing.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm.

Comment: Mac crashed my login (not a full reboot).  On logging back in, all running apps restarted putting the Java process in some weird zombie state (my best guess).  Killing the Java process in activity manager fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Solution is to close Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

Solution

1.Just clean the project and check its working or not

2.Just Restart android studio after closing all the rubbish tasks

3.If both the above things not working add this in  gradle.build file

```
android {

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
    }

}
```

Comment: nice and 3 one working.

Answer (score 7):

Use the option `assembleandroidtest` as in the image below. So you can find out more about the error occurred:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution!!! to find out exact problem!!!

Comment: Thanks , Its perfect

Comment: Thank u man. This saved our day. Also Pelin say thank you too.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after adding the library *icepick* to my gradle dependencies. After removing the dependencie, everything seems to be fine. As soon as i know why this issue appeared i'll write here again

Comment: Same here.  The fix was to use `provided` instead of `compile` for the `processor` dependency.  See [this ticket](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick/issues/46).

Answer (score 3):

After adding a jar file to a project's lib folder and after adding it to the build.gradle file as **compile'path example'** when you sync the gradle it add an additional line as **compile files('libs/example.jar')**. You just need to remove the line you previously added to the build.gradle file i.e. the compile'path example' after the gradle sync. You also need to remove the line **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')**

Comment: In your case just remove the line compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']). Hope it will work fine for you.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I do not know why this is so difficult for me iOS adding dependencies and managing these is wayyyy more simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

add this to your gradle Build. It worked for me

Comment: that doesn't work for me

Comment: @letsdev-cwack did you have same problem ??

Answer (score 3):

The answer for me was to free memory to the build process, closing programing or rebooting the machine (win10 seems to manage memory worse than win7)

Why did it fixed for me?

During the build, android studio doesn't find enough memory to compile but **it doesnt show any error**. The :app:preDexDebug error happened just when I tried to upload the compiled app to the phone.

Sometimes I could get through this point (no app:preDexDebug error),  but when running the application on android I got "ClassNotFound" exceptions. This was the clue to discover android studio wasn't compiling all my files during build because of the lack of memory (win10 asked me to close android studio to save memory during the build), even though the IDE showing me that the build was successful.

Comment: This more like question about the exceptions or a comment rather than an answer. If this is an answer please mention how you fixed all the exceptions you are mentioning about, if this is a new question ask a new question about the previously you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Tried to make myself clear. I dont master English, but I spent some hours in this problem that i decided to post what worked for me. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning and rebuilding the project works for me. In Android studio:

```
Build -> Clean Project 
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180013/1233979)

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I have tried virtually everything until I tried to run the script from error in command line:

```
dx.bat -JXmx1536m --dex --output \build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-01b5c6cd66151f573da9773c18af55d10736a24e.jar build\intermediates\exploded-aar\aaa-release\classes.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Then I commented out developer's memory setting in gradle script:

```
//        javaMaxHeapSize "1536m"
```

and I was able to pass this error. I need to increase RAM in my laptop.

Comment: how did you set javaMaxHeapSize? I set it using gradle.properties, but it only works for gradle daemon.

Comment: javaMaxHeapSize is a property under `android.dexOptions`. I had it at 3gb myself at a Win10 install with 16GB ram. Decreasing it to 1 or removing it fixed it (ironically) for me

Comment: Yes, also strangely enough decreasing it to 1gb in my project from 3gb worked. I have plenty of RAM so very strange.

Answer (score 1):

You must update all blocks in SDK Manager (Support Library, etc.), all non updated libs and packages. After this you must sync gradle files with project and rejoice!

Answer (score 1):

In my case setting Java Max Heap Size from 2g to 1g worked.

Add following to application module's build.gradle file

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me

Install Java JDK 8.

Then, go to Tools-> Options ->Tools for Apache Cordova-> Environment Variable Overrides and set the path to your JDK to "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121" to get Java 8 instead of Java 7.

for more info http://www.developersite.org/103-141954-android

Answer (score 1):

Experimental I found way:

App extends Application **not** MultiDexApplication

and remove

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

from gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after transferring my project from my laptop to my desktop in Android Studio.

My solution was to restart Android Studio, then clean the project and finally execute the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after trying each of the answers here, I noticed that a package which I had renamed had not been renamed in a class which imported it. I fixed the name and immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your app exceeding the 65k method count, thus causing a dex error.  There is no solution, other than enabling multidexing in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well there can be many problems associated with it. First of all check whether you messed up with some file placements. for example what I did is I placed non xml file in anim folder, which isn't allowed. So check whether such things happened to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled multidexing?. Do extend your main Application class with MultiDexApplication. I have got additional exception mesage before the error. They are as follows.

```
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2 errors; aborting
```

This clearly tells that the error occurred due to out of memory. Try the following:

1. extend your main Application class with MultiDexApplication.
2. close unused applications from background and restart Android Studio.

This will do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give this mother a chance:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'
    }
```

Don't forget to bookmark [this](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue just now, and it turned out to be caused by a faulty `attrs.xml` file in one of my modules. The file initially had two stylable attributes for one of my custom views, but I had deleted one when it turned out I no longer needed it. This was apparently, however, not registered correctly with the IDE and so the build failed when it couldn't find the attribute.

The solution for me was to re-add the attribute, run a `clean project` after which the build succeeded and I could succesfully remove the attribute again without any further problems.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There's many reason that leads to

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

If you are not hitting the dex limit but you are getting error similar to this `Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: name already added: string{"a"}`

Try disable proguard, if it manage to compile without issue then you will need to figure out which library caused it and add it to `proguard-rules.pro` file

In my case this issue occur when I updated `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`

One of the workaround is I added this to `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
## Google AdMob specific rules ##
## https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start ##

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}
```

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem with a joking way. I have two class with names `startDl` and `StartDl`. I just change one of them to `StartDownload` and my problem solved. also can resources have a name that already is reserved with anymore resource in project. just rename similar names to different.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to kill some of the running process and free the space on your Memory(RAM). You can try closing some of the high memory consuming program. You can also try restarting the Android Studio. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the line:

```
('com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0')
```

From dependencies (in `build.gradle`):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: And why do you think it would work, please explain so we understand

Answer (score -2):

For me this works:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```