# aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android

I have problem,
When I run my app that write:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Tomas\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Can any help me?

Comment: Update your build tool then and restart

Comment: I've tried it , unfortunately it did not work

Comment: there's an error description above this. these two lines alone will tell us nothing really.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

At first you go to "**Build**"-> "**Clean Project**"

and then go to "**Build**" -> "**Rebuild Project**"

link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180013/4451507

Answer (score 1):

Change The buildToolsVersion To compileSdkVersion as Shown Below Code:...

Before: It Was Not Working....

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kdmsl.kraapp'
        minSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
    }
```

After Changes:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kdmsl.kraapp'
        minSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one more solution for this query...

just check the .xml or layout file which you recently modified or added views(like any thing Textview,EditText,Button...) you might be missing something(like background images, or string value etc) for views

-Work For Sure 
@Ambilpura Sunil