# android: Execution failed for task error

Tags: android, build, gradle, compiler-errors

when i try to build my android application or sync gradle i get this error : `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android Development\sdk\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

[i use last version of build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450620/aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

how can i slove this problem ?