# Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I just generated a project in libgdx and imported to eclipse, compiled a few dependencies and now I get this:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugAidl'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Progrmor\Workspace\android-sdks\build-tools\22.0.1\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I´ve tried refreshing gradle, installing the latest build tools etc, but this still remains.

And here´s the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
}}allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = 'Tone'
    gdxVersion = '1.6.0'
    roboVMVersion = '1.2.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
    ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
    aiVersion = '1.5.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}}project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
}}project(":android") {

apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
}}project(":ios") {
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "robovm"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
}}project(":html") {
apply plugin: "gwt"
apply plugin: "war"


dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion:sources"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
}}project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
}}tasks.eclipse.doLast {
delete ".project"

}
```

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value maybe help you

Comment: Check the version of your Android plugin for gradle

Comment: check this method 1 inside http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/32350792#32350792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a little old, but I recently encountered and resolved this problem.  Since there's no answer and the links could not help me here, I'll go ahead and leave my solution.

This happened to me after renaming my app's package.

What worked was removing the current aidl folder that was set up for in-app billing, recreating the folders and moving the iinappbilling.aidl from '/extras/google/play_billing' into 'app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing'.  Then (which was most people's answer in the links provided from the comments) I ran clean + rebuild and gradle ran and my build was successful.

Hope this helps someone having this issue.