# finished with non-zero exit value 1 error occurs

Tags: android

This error occurs everytime i try to run any code in external device for debugging in android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: please share your gradle file, you might need to enable multidex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325253/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

can help yours 
or clean and rebuild project.