# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' Cannot resolve Symbol 'R'

Tags: android

Here is the Gradle build error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Srecko\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Everything was OK a day before, and on my notebook is still OK if I copy code.
I reinstall Windows :D and Android Studio, but problem is still here

Gradle is:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.spirit.dukomplinalpha"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.5"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
    // YOUR OTHER DEPENDENCIES
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'  //  material dialog
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'  //  material buttons and stuff
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile files('libs/sjxp-2.0.jar')
}
```

In Fragments error is:

```
Cannot resolve Symbol 'R'
```

any ideas how to solve this problem, where is the real error?
thx

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: ofc that is allways first thing to try ;)

Answer (score 0):

better to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value) all case for your project. 
 because there are many possible cases for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could setting compileSdkVersion and others to the latest. And than find the comfort picture to  match the ui version, click build->rebuild, maybe could solve !!