# Android Studio Error After Update

Tags: android

I have just updated my Android Studio, then it asked if i would like to import my settings where I said no and started new as I wanted to start fresh. Then I have created a new project.
On doing this in the mainactivity.java the R's are red in color. Also when i try running this Hello World program(default app that is made when creating the program) , 3 errors show up which are-

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
>       name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
>       name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>       com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>       org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users
>       \Kalyan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished 
>       with non-zero exit value 1

I am not sure what to do it would be real nice if someone could help me out.
-Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I faced the same problem. I created new work space and copied my project in that workspace and then switched to newly created workspace solved my problem.
I hope this will solve your problem. 
You can visit for more assistance.
[finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)

Comment: Create new project -> Select Project Location.
Care to be taken that there should not be any blank space in Project Location Path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I ran updates. I first tried to sync project with `gradle` files, but that did not work for me. What did work was that I went to:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules: app (left column) -> Properties tab.
```

Under that tab you have both:

```
"Compile Sdk Version" 
"Build Tools Version"
```

I think one was version `23` or `22` and the other was version `21`. Don't remember exactly. All I remember is that they didn't match. So I made them match. I set the `"Compile Sdk Version"` to `23` and the `"Build Tools Version"` to `23.0.1` and the problem was solved. So use which ever you want, I guess, `23` and `23`, `22` and `22`, etc.