# Android studio shows these errors whenever a new project is created

Tags: android, gradle

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sarthakalang/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: post your build.gradle please

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I faced the same problem. I created new work space and copied my project in that workspace and then switched to newly created workspace solved my problem. I hope this will solve your problem. You can visit for more assistance.[finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)

or

Create new project -> Select Project Location. Care to be taken that there should not be any blank space in Project Location Path.