# Can't run an application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

i am new to Android Studio and Android programming with very less knowledge. While trying to execute a program a error is shown

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: >org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program >Files >(x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with >non-zero exit value 1.

I am using Android Studio version 1.3.1 My compileSdkVersion is 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"and targetSdkVersion 23.
lease help, thanx!

Comment: Go through this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value

Comment: As i said, im new and so i can't understand that thread. It would be nice if someone can help me in simpler way... ty

Comment: Post your build.gradle. Also launch the command gradlew assembleDebug --info. In this way you will have more info about the gradle process.