# No resource found that matches the given name.dont load any drawable image

Tags: android, android-studio

I put a background image in drawable folder and use it in background activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>
```

Every time I run the project, I get the following error:

C:\ASP\InstaFollowerPlus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_main.xml
Error:(21, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/background').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Software\Computer engineer software\Android SDK full\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.

i tried Clean Project and failed.

compileSdkVersion 23,
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1',
Android Studio: 1.2.1.1

[image]

Comment: Means image with `background` name not available in Drawable folder

Comment: Did you solve this yet ??

Answer (score 3):

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with
>   value '@drawable/background').

1. Please add images in your respective **drawable folder** first
2. use `compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion '23.0.1',`
3. Post your *build.gradle* please . Remove unwanted (Duplicate) File
4. use **Android Studio: 1.3** (Stable Version)
5. Then Clean and build project And Sync Project
6. Check your images are **properly .PNG** formatted or not

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cad.ir.instafollowerplus"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}

Comment: @CenaAv Please post this in your question section

Comment: @CenaAv Okay .No problem .Please upgrade your repository

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/31180013#31180013

Comment: I just changed .png to.jpg and works! do you have any idea how this works?

Comment: @CenaAv At first ,Glad to hear that your problem solved .For your question , I guess your Images are not proper PNG formatted

Comment: @CenaAv I would expect `PNG` to scale slightly better .

Comment: @CenaAv Cheers ! Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

`Rename` the Image via right clicking on it and selecting the `Refactor>Rename`. And then run it it might run.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoTangan"` to define `imageID`, then use the same (`@+id/imageViewLogoTangan`) in your another code