# Android Studio 2.0, org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command Error finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-2.0

I am experimenting with the new android studio IDE 2.0 , Project was working fine with studio 1.5 . After Migration I am geeting the following Error-

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/manishpathak/AndroidStudioProjects/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
  >   ' BUILD FAILED

Already enabled

> ```
>    multiDexEnabled true
> ```

in build.gradle.

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: try cleaning build and then rebuilding.

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project at least 10 times , but no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value      ./gradlew assembleDebug --info and check what actually generate the error on the gradle build, it might be all sorts of various problems.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks All. The following solution fixed my issue- Java wanted more space to build the project. I found the java process and analysed after 1 GB, process halted. Java needs more memory.

**FIXED SOLUTION:** Increased the HEAP size to 2g or 4g.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {}

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
    }

    buildTypes {
    } }
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'javaMaxHeapSize'. Probably does not work the latest build tools/gradle

Comment: @ivy_the you might misplaced the `dexoption`,  put it as a child of android in your module (located build.gradle in app dir ) gradle file. let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: you are right, I should have put it in android section

Answer (score 0):

i just added this ,and then its all ok and my issue was solved :

```
/* compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' */
```