# aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero > exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio

I import a project in android studio. This project has SDK higher than my SDK. I update my SDK but i see this error for project:
23-0-1-aapt-exe finished with non zero exit value 1.
I test other SDK like:23.0.2, 21.1.2, 21.1.1 but this error still there is. I cleaned project and rebuilt in many time but did not solve my problem. Here is my SDK:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMSM8.jpg)

Here is my gradle details:

```
  android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
  }

 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 695
}
```

I need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finished with non zero exit value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your Manifest.xml file to point to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`? Since you have SDK build tools for version 22, roll your target version back to 22 and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I updated Manifest.xml file. Now try SDK build tools v.22 but my problem dose not sole.

Comment: Can you post the entire error message you are getting?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':Project:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: You are most likely referencing something that either doesn't exist or has a conflicting resource. As suggested by @HrundiBakshi look into duplicate post. Open command prompt Cd to project folder, and run command gradlew assembleDebug --info. This should narrow down your error. Please post error message received.

Comment: libraries in my Dependencies are V.21.0.3 but in project has used V.23.1.+. I changed them to my version. Do you think my problem is for this change?

Comment: Most likely you are compiling for V21 and not V23. If you fixed this dependency try to recompile the program again and see if the error persists.

Comment: yes by your guidance. thank you very very much. you save my time.

Comment: Would you mind marking as answered? Just click the check mark next to my original comment. Glad to help!