# Libgdx doesn't load app on Android phone

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm creating a game using LibGDX on Android Studio. When I run it on the desktop executable, it works perfectly. But when I try to run it on my phone, the code doesn't compile because of an issue:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This is my android .gradle:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.globapps.supermarioclon"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what does this message mean? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finished with non zero exit value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)