# android studio FAILURE: Build failed with an exception finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, build.gradle

After update Android studio to Version 2.1.1, I try to run old project from existing source but project Can't build project

Error I can see is :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

in Gradle I have :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app.prjname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 120
        versionName "1.20"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("D:\\Android\\signkey\\Project\\prjname\\prjname.jks")
            storePassword "mypassword"
            keyAlias "prjnameAlias"
            keyPassword "mypassword"
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

command-line options is empty

Gradle is not `offline mode` and set on `use default gradle wraper`

I try many solutions, clear Rebuild, Invalidate cache and restart

but not works

Message Gradle Build :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-17;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-17\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-17\default\armeabi-v7a')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsistent location 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-19\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-19\default\armeabi-v7a')
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComGithubSatyanSugar14Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase901Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement901Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps901Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks901Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon901Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 15.252 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Try to build project form command line with gradlw assembleBuild :

```
    Unzipping C:\Users\android\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\5b6kqrscumh9p4e
vkkemdk57ad\gradle-2.10-all.zip to C:\Users\android\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle
-2.10-all\5b6kqrscumh9p4evkkemdk57ad
44> Configuring > 0/2 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpa
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent locati
on 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'D:\dev\ide\
sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-17;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsiste
nt location 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-17\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'D:\
dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-17\default\armeabi-v7a')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a' in inconsiste
nt location 'D:\dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-19\armeabi-v7a' (Expected 'D:\
dev\ide\sdk\system-images\android-19\default\armeabi-v7a')
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleBuild' not found in root project 'prjname'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option
 to get the stack trace. Run with                                              -
-info
or                                                                             -
-debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16 mins 5.454 secs
```

Comment: post your complete app's build.gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finished with non zero exit value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see error message, you can build project form command line with gradlw assembleBuild, it contains much more info.

Comment: Open terminal, for Windows press WIN+R and type "cmd".
Navigate to project root dirrectory via "cd" command.
And type "gradlew assembleBuild"

Comment: Try gradlew assembleDebugBuild or simple gradlew build

Comment: Ususally this line "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'." means that there is some error in resources like: Invalid resources names, or invalid 9png format

Comment: finally i found problem, it is because i put some files in assets folder with non English characters (Farsi, Iranian Language) after rename whole of them project running successfully

Answer (score 1):

1.Delete build folder inside from project
2.Clean Project
3.Rebuild Project
4.Run Project

This helps me so many times hope this will helps to you too.

Comment: No, i told, even Invalid cache and restart not worked

Comment: please not that this happens also when we put non relevance files to non relevance folders like sometimes we put drawable images into layout resource folder so please make sure this does not done by you :)

Comment: Please Read My Comments On @oleg-vladimirov Post

Comment: ohk great :) thats what i am talking about also