# When i open my project it will be come to this error non-zero exit value 126,how to overcome this?

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 126

Comment: Can u post the complete log?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value) thread

Answer (score 1):

try Build->Clean Project and then Build->Rebuild Project.

Comment: Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 126

Answer (score 0):

try File>`Invalidate Chaches / Restart` this will work

and ADD this

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Not getting again come to this Error:Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 126

Comment: use multiDexEnable true in defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Comment: where i add that config ?

Comment: in you Gradle:App find it you will see this at the top some where under ` `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`