# Error in android studio when trying to build the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I am trying to build an android project from android studio version 3.0.1. When I try to compile my project I stuck into this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.parse:parse-android:1.16.7] E:\codecanyon-19950163-whatsapp-status-downloader\WhatsDownloader\WI Video Downloader\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.parse\parse-android\1.16.7\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.parse" to force usage

Please suggest a solution to solve this solution but i cannot fix this issue

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kingdov.whatsapp_status_downloader"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "KINGDOV"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.2.2'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar'

}
```

Now I am getting this from the stack trace

- Exception is:

  > > org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
  > >     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(module: app)**

search for

```
defaultConfig {
    ...........
    minSdkVersion 11 //change this to 14
    ..........
}
```

Comment: then i get this Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\RamRo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: I would rather suggest you install the latest version of you build tools.See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29431747/8553954

Comment: Hey, can you post your stack trace after changing the sdkVersion.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\RamRo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your minimum `API` cant be lower than 14 because of a `library`. To fix, go to `File`, `Project Structure`,Then under `Modules` click `App`, then `Flavors` and change in the textbox `minSdk`   to something **higher** than 14. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the  offical way of changing the `minSDK`