# Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, build.gradle

So I am having this error every time I try to sync my project on android studio

The error

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my **build.grable** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newcoderplus.moneymachinecash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
    maven { url "https://bitbucket.org/adscend/androidsdk/raw/master/" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-adapters" }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':fragmentation_swipeback')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v6.0.0_2016-10-21.jar')
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.5.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.1.3'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.1'
    compile 'com.jude:easyrecyclerview:4.4.0'
    compile 'com.jude:rollviewpager:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
    compile 'me.yokeyword:fragmentation:0.10.4'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.backendless', name: 'backendless', version: '4.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.ironsource.adapters:admobadapter:3.0.2@jar'
    compile 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.5.3@jar'
    compile project(':fragmentation_swipeback')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v6.0.0_2016-10-21.jar')
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.5.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have the lastest version of android studio as of today

Something is not working with my android studio. I am using latest version of Android studio, still it gives me error on gradle build. Any ideas on how I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265966/7705712

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue yesterday. with no clue what to do. **So google it**. But whatever material I came across, had **no exact solution for the prob**., seems like different things were working for different people.

> Here is my observation that can save your time.
>   1. Please verify, if you've messed anywhere with resources like strings, dimens, colors or in layout xml files.

```
By mistake I created some prob. with my strings xml file along with layout file.
```

> Even clean build was not working, the same error kept popping after
>   every rebuild/clean.

```
You have to look closely, to identify the prob. with your code.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First try to clean and rebuild your project from Build menu.

Step 1: go to **Build -> Clean Project**

Step 2: go to **Build -> Rebuild Project**

This should solve your problem.

Otherwise **try updating Android SDK build tool from SDK manager** and modify your build.gradle to use latest buildToolsVersion i.e "27.0.3" as of now

Comment: i did this and it work most of times but this time it didn't and as you see my  buildToolsVersion is "25.0.2"

Comment: change buildToolsVersion to 27.0.3 and try again

Comment: same error again "Process 'command 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
"