# updated android studio to 3.2.1 and I'm stuck

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on an android application for which I got help for a lot of question from here. Thanks
but
now I'm stuck on "cannot resolve R" from a couple of days.
I tried to work on 3 different applications and all I got is errors like that
I don't know if this is a problem of android studio

**android version**

[image]

**errors which I been receiving since ages I think**

[image]

this ain't gradle.build[app] of above-mentioned project but is of another app as it's not building gradle when I restarted it now,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visionapps.demo.swipe"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/otto-1.3.3.jar')
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value

Comment: Try using Gradle build from the terminal to better diagnose the errors

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: @cricket_007 how to do that? writing "%gardlew%" command in cmd ?

Comment: @Jeeva build.gradle[project] or [app] ?

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 yes i did

Comment: build.gradle for app

Comment: @Jeeva i posted it

Comment: Yes. `.\gradlew.bat compile`  assuming windows... Also the image shows you're actually using build tools 25.0.3, so are you sure that Gradle file is correct?

Comment: @cricket_007 i told there that it is not of that project, would you mind telling me the command

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You need to change to the directory of your project first

Comment: can you post project structure screenshot

Comment: @danishali like cricket_007 mentioned is this the correct build file,you happened to post the same screenshot for another different question

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, On the menu **File** -> **Project Structure** : **change the default JDK location directory** to your own:

> /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111 #path_to_your_jdk

[image]

Comment: no, it didn't solve :/ either it started giving error about java jdk

Answer (score 0):

Change your compile sdk version to 24

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
```

Comment: NO,,, it didn't help,. i have tried all such answers before asking this question

Comment: change your buildToolsVersion

Comment: i cant find any build tools version 24.0.0 so kindly check

Comment: i now have  compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3" but "build fails"

Comment: Ideally, you use the latest build tools and SDK with the latest IDE

Comment: Did you create any custom style file for your project

Comment: @cricket_007 i do.. :/

Comment: @Jeeva no i dont

Comment: @danish Version 24 of the Android SDK is not the latest