# Gradle downloading wrong version of appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a strange problem. I have an old Android APP developed in the times of Android 6.0. Now I wanted to do some small changes and yes I know I should move to SDK 28, but it is not a simple task, so it will take some time. The app uses appcompat-v7.

I have installed Android Studio 3.3 imported the project and of course added to download the appcompat-v7 from Google maven.
In dependence I have

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

but Gradle downloads appcompat-v7:27.0.2

Why? appcompat-v7:27.0.2 is causing the build process to fail:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\java\android_sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The cause of this is

```
\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\27.0.2\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
```

How can I force Gradle to use v24 of the appcompat?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/31180013#31180013

Comment: try delete app/build folder or if you are using linux then search and delete from this folder as well ~/.gradle/caches/

Comment: I did all that before and even more:
- clean & rebuild
- delete build dir
- even re-imported the code from git as a new project