# Execution failed for task :app:Debug Process exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error while executing my app after I updated my SDK for 23.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My build.gradle looks is like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.movieschannel'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.01"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for many reasons. Sometimes '**Clean**' the project will fix it. Please check the solutions posted here  [Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)