# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I face a unknown type of error`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

My build.gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

}

My Logtag is here:-

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDaimajiaSliderLibrary115Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:542)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/catalyst/android/shoppingmazza/activity/MainActivity$setImageView) does not match path (com/catalyst/android/shoppingmazza/activity/MainActivity$SetImageView.class)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 25.634 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: please add the complete stack trace of the error

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1 have you tried these answers?

Comment: Yes I checked but i find no suitable answer for me

Comment: In your application do you have DirectClassFile.java?

Comment: No  DirectClassFile.java name in my application

Comment: Do you have Inner class in your MainActivity/AnyActiviy...which you have used in some other class file?...I would suggest to restart your Android Studio by invalidating cache and then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 3):

This steps worked for me:

- Uninstall the app in your phone/emulator
- Go to *Build* menu and then click in *Clean Project*
- Run the app again

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12154669)

Comment: How does this not attempt to provide an answer, @Robert? It's not terribly high quality, but it sure looks like an answer.

Comment: In Android Studio I go to _Build_ menu, then to _Clean Project_ and when it finished, I run the app again and it worked fine. And before this steps I uninstall the app in the phone. That worked for me.

Comment: Uninstalling the app from the target device was key

Answer (score 1):

i want to try to help, because i faced the same problem with you. And this is what i did to my project

1. try to change the buildToolsVersion from "23.0.1" to "23.0.0" or another
   version
2. clean the project
3. rebuild project

i think it is the bug from the Android SDK buildToolVersion

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only error log you get? Nothing more detailed? You can try adding this to your gradle file inside android tag.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Comment: And your error log isn't more detailed? Just what you posted?

Comment: @ThomasR. Its a very popular problem

Comment: Did you perform a sync/clean of the project after changing the gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether this is the right answer or not. But this occurs if some of your jar files does not compile properly.

You can sync your project again before cleaning, or you can delete the last jar file added, and then sync.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your app - this line:

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/catalyst/android/shoppingmazza/activity/MainActivity$setImageView) does not match path (com/catalyst/android/shoppingmazza/activity/MainActivity$SetImageView.class)
```

Looks like you have `setImageView` somewhere when it should be `SetImageView` - in an XML file perhaps?