# Gradle Build error ':app:preDexDebug' - return 1 finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> :app:dexDebug

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

Comment: Post your `gradle` file too.. Though, Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1 ..

Comment: Most common question .Please post your `build.gradle`