# Android Studio - Issue in build.gradle uncaught translation error ExecutionException OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am having a strange problem with my Android app in Android Studio. Everything seemed to be working fine, until today after adding some *new files* and making some updates to **build.gradle**.

The error message I am seeing is the following:

```
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
6 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':myapplication:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Do you know if there is any issue with my build.gradle below? The new lines are under "**NEW DEPENDENCIES ADDED BELOW THIS LINE**". I also set multiDexEnabled to true.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    //useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar')
    compile files('libs/multiscreen-android-1.1.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'

    /* NEW DEPENDENCIES BELOW THIS LINE */
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' 
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    // Used to optimize rendering of list views
    // compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' 
    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to run your script with this option in your android closure:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

This will increase the maximum heap size for dex operations. You can find some explanation [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750404/android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g)

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @android-user you're welcome) added the link to another question, where this option is described alittle