# To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 910 MB

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-daemon

I am getting this Gradle error every time I run my app. The error is:

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
>   It currently has approximately 910 MB.
>
> For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
>
> To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
>   For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Here is my build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "mobileapp.tech2dsk"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    }
```

And here is my build.gradle(Project) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my gradle.properties file :

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 53):

**Update from June 25, 2017**

At Google IO 2017 there was some updates about this topic. It's not recommended anymore to set the flag on the dexOptions, so if you have something like the next, you can delete it.

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

- Source: [Speeding Up Your Android Gradle Builds](https://youtu.be/7ll-rkLCtyk?t=18m50s)

**Original answer:**

Android Studio 2.1 enables Dex In Process which shares the VM with Gradle to improve build times. Due to this, it's necessary to increase the size of the Gradle daemon to incorporate those Dex processes.

At least it's necessary 2 gigs of memory, but you can try with three if you can afford it.

gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m
```

By default the Java max heap size is one gig, but in case you have modified it on the build.gradle file...

build.gradle (App)

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

...you have to resize the Gradle daemon size accordingly (has to be bigger to fit the heap).

- Resources

  1. [Official blog post by Reto Meier](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.4ns1qvlji)
  2. [Official Video in Android
     Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SY5nkNVUn0)
  3. [DexOptions docs.](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html)

Notes:

- Please realize above numbers varies from machine to machine.

Comment: For those using Ionic to build an app, you can `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m` to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: This answer should be accept as the right one. Thanks, btw

Comment: On Android Studio 3.0 removing javaMaxHeapSize entirely decreased my incremental build times from 90 seconds to 7 seconds.

Comment: For years I had this in my gradle, currently at 4g, and hated that it would always have to be tended to (raised) as time went on. Now apparently I can just get rid this clutter. Eliminating it reduced my gradle build time immensely, as commented by dell116.

Comment: in 2023, what is the best option for this? org.gradle.jvmargs=-XXX

Answer (score 51):

Add in your Build.gradle

```
android {
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

More info - [Android Gradle: What is javaMaxHeapSize "4g"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750404/android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g)

Comment: in Module app or in project file

Comment: build.gradle (Module app)

Comment: if u dont mind can u plz telll me why do these error occurs

Comment: sorry this also doesnt work getting same error with chnage in numbers

Comment: How much RAM memory do you have on your workstation? Java may not be able to provide required memory if not available( just a thought though)

Comment: I set mine to `2g` and it was very happy

Comment: You also have to add org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m 
You can change the number 2048 according to the ram you are allotting in the heap.

Comment: Technically if you are setting max heap size to 4g you'd need to change to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m

Answer (score 25):

Simply leave that on your gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

You can look at [that article as reference.](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.x00peol9f)

Comment: Fantastic! The problem was driving me nuts and this sorted it out immediately. Thanks

Comment: in cordova projects, the gradle.properties file should be created in platforms/android/gradle.properties

Comment: I am not finding that file.I only have project.properties

Answer (score 15):

I know it's too late for the answer but hope it will helpful to someone

I have tried lot of thing and search lot but nothing works for me include following and **build.gradle (App)** also dosen't work in my case

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

Also You Can Try Add on your **gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

In my case the problem is cpu utilization there is lot of process running while i build apk i just kill some processes like genymotion,skype,safari etc and than invalidate caches/restart it works for me.

Comment: commended, thanks probably because the overall project size is way to big for default java heap size, still thanks. keep it rocking brother !

Answer (score 7):

Modify or create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory.

For Mac,
/Users/USER_NAME/.gradle/gradle.properties

For Linux,
/home/USER_NAME/.gradle/gradle.properties

For Windows,
C:\Users\USER_NAME.gradle\gradle.properties

and apply the above changes. Finally it should look like,

```
org.gradle.daemon=true

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Please refer this link
https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/android-speed-up-gradle-build-process-in-android-studio/

Comment: "above" ? Maybe you mean something like "following" ?

Comment: There is no gradle.properties file in that location

Comment: Thanks! Tried everything and this was only one that worked for me! Java seemed to be ignoring all other settings as listed in gradle.properties and build.gradle etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can go ahead and change `build.gradle` like that (like Veeresh Charantimath suggested):

```
android {
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
 }
}
```

And then you might have to mess around with [MultiDex stuff](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) (you will need it for big android projects). **But** your problem may be simpler. There is some chance that you compile and include in your project some not needed libraries. I faced this issue on my tiny project. Here is what I did to fix it:

I removed this from `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And I manually removed my build folder from application root. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Is it an error or a warning?

Sometimes this is only a warning and I can manage to build it successfully:

```
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug
:zipalignDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 44.991 secs
Built the following apk(s):
(...)
```

So the problem that may prevent a successful build may be another one...

Answer (score 2):

In WINDOW'S open the gradle.properties from ~\Users\**UserName**\.gradle as shown below:  for more info [enter link description here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

[image]

***and make sure to set its value to minimum to 4608M as shown below for faster builds***
***org.gradle.jvmargs*=-Xmx4608M**

Once you do that then you can see the day and night difference in speed building your app...

Comment: There is no file with name: `gradle.properties` in `C:\Users\USER\.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `javaMaxHeapSize` and `org.gradle.jvmargs` are mutually exclusive.

- `javaMaxHeapSize` is the old way of doing it, with dex run outside of the process. This will be an argument to the dex process.
- `org.gradle.jvmargs` is the new way of doing it, with dex inside the gradle process. This is the max memory for the whole process (gradle, including dex)

What the warning says is that `org.gradle.jvmargs` should be >= `javaMaxHeapSize (what you used previously for dex)` + `512M (an estimation of what's needed for gradle own needs)`.

So if you want to use dex in process (which is faster), you shouldn't care about `javaMaxHeapSize`. Just set `org.gradle.jvmargs` to a correct value for your project/machine.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208214

Using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2` I set `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3415M` with `dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize "2g"` and the error message went away.

Answer (score 1):

- Please check at first gradle.propertises at your project root directory.

If it is absence, please create a file as like this , then add org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

otherwise if already there , please increase the size.

I have faced same problem , where i have solved by this way.

Answer (score 1):

Example, in `gradle.properties` of your project root.

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Hello 
Your answer isn't adressing problem, You are drowning yourself as well as users of SO. Please remove this answer to get your positive rating back. Thank You.