# Increasing the gradle heap size

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, heap-memory

Whenever I try to make the build of the app , gradle takes too much of time and there comes a message showing that you should increase the Gradle size to 3072 MB , currently it is 910 MB . so my question is how can I increase the heap memory of gradle ??

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090135/to-run-dex-in-process-the-gradle-daemon-needs-a-larger-heap-it-currently-has-a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add

```
 android {
 ....
 dexOptions {
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

in your `build.gradle` file