# Reduce Build time in android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my android app,  it takes approximately more than 3 minutes to build the app. If I browse through the build tasks one by one, I noticed that `app:lintDebug` takes the considerable amount of minutes (more than 1 minute)

It is quite annoying and i was aware to disable lint check ,  by putting these settings

```
lintOptions {
    tasks.lint.enabled = false
    quiet false
    abortOnError false
    ignoreWarnings false
    warningsAsErrors true
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

**Also in the top of the file**

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "lint") {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Also I have checked the offline Gradle build aswel.

**But yet**

[image]

Is there any others settings that i need to put to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually build time depends on your module count. I give you some advice which use on my project(7 module)

- Disable Instant Run.
- [Configure Gradle](https://gist.github.com/lwasyl/7d75540978b483e0fb75266262716800#file-gradle-properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203884/increasing-the-gradle-heap-size)
- If you use DexGuard or ProGuard, turn off while debug build.
- If you use Crashlytics, check library version. It may be cause negative effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work on offline mode after adding dependencies.If you want to add more dependencies just disable offline mode add dependency and then again enable offline mode. This will save a lot of your build time.I am working on a large project where build time on online mode is almost an hour while on offline mode it took some minutes to build.

```
To enable or disable offline mode go to: 

 -> File
 -> Settings 
 -> Build,Execution,Development -> Gradle
 -> Checked or unchecked offline work
```

Comment: Already its in offline mode,  my question is why does the lint checks even if its disabled . Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it done by using a different task name ,  the gradle build for lint check has placed as lintDebug instead of lint updated skipping lint check should placed   as follow

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "lintDebug") {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```