# i get executionexception and large heap error

Tags: android, processexception

For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 3072 MB.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.

To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072M in the project gradle.properties.
It currently has approximately 989 MB.

For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "videoplayer.avkinfosoft.com.videoplayer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    packagingOptions
            {
                pickFirst 'META-INF/license.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

### gradle.propties

Project-wide Gradle settings.

IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
 Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
 any settings specified in this file.

For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
 http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
 The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
 Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
 This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
 http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
 org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

org.gradle.daemon=true

When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
 This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true

### manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:icon">
```

### after chnage error

```
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
```

Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program

Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M in the project gradle.properties.

Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

It currently has approximately 989 MB.

For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 5120 MB.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:largeHeap="true"` in your MenifestFile in application tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should add **`javaMaxHeapSize`**  in `build.gradle` section .

```
android {
compileSdkVersion //
buildToolsVersion //


dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

You can visit for more information **[Android Gradle: What is javaMaxHeapSize “4g”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750404/android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g)**

Comment: what are the down side of this line? can you please elaborate that too?

Comment: i use this in my gradle but not any type of effect

Comment: @Manish post your `build.gradle` in question section

Comment: @Manish read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090135/to-run-dex-in-process-the-gradle-daemon-needs-a-larger-heap-it-currently-has-a

Comment: i view and follow that link but then after runtime show this error at apk install time.

Comment: @Manish set 4g instead of 2g .clean-rebuild and run