# OutOfMemoryError with Adobe Sitecatalyst

Tags: android, adobe, adobe-analytics

I am having adobe sitecatalyst in my android application,
and found several crashes with below mentioned stacktrace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: int[] of length 1674283432 exceeds the VM limit
       at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:196)
       at android.util.ArrayMap.ensureCapacity(ArrayMap.java:307)
       at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:247)
       at android.os.Bundle.containsKey(Bundle.java:299)
       at com.adobe.mobile.ReferrerHandler.getReferrerURLFromIntent(SourceFile:97)
       at com.adobe.mobile.ReferrerHandler.processIntent(SourceFile:63)
       at com.adobe.mobile.Analytics$10.run(SourceFile:211)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Somewhere in adobe analytics code, its creating array of bigger size. 
**Any solution for this ?**

Answer (score 0):

I research about the error you faced in your application and I found 2 answers, they all sed to change the **javaMaxHeapSize** to "4g" inside **dexOptions**
please check the following link, hope it will work

[Android - Java heap space error](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205490006-Android-Java-heap-space-error)

[android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33751673/2621857)

[Increase heap size](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/P_TLBTyFWVY/4TPJ2YY6khUJ)

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment.
but yours is related to jvm heap while building application.
My application is crashing on production not while building.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Application Tag of Manifest file..

```
<application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: Hello, I can't get your point.
I already set largeheap parameter
and android:vmSafeMode just disables AOT in ART, 

I guess the issue is in Adobe code (maybe?)

Comment: @Prashant yes it might be issue. but have you set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ?