# javaMaxHeapSize vs android:largeHeap

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've just learned a new way to set jvm heap size instead of settings in **gradle.properties** using `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M` is setting in **app/build.gradle**:

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
}
```

But I want to know what are the differences between this and `android:largeHeap="true"` in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Thank you!

Comment: have look  [android:largeHeap="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/what-are-advantages-of-setting-largeheap-to-true) and [javaMaxHeapSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750404/android-gradle-what-is-javamaxheapsize-4g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaMaxHeapSize: the heap size for the dex process, **It is for speeding up the build gradle**

LargeHeap: Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory. **It is for allocating more memory to run application on RAM.**

JavaMaxHeapSize: https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed

LargeHeap:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: So JavaMaxHeapSize is for the APK building process, and LargeHeap is for actually heap size on devices?