# Finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

**Problem Solved:**
**Re-installed Java and got**
    *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded*
**Added the following within the android block in gradle and it worked**
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
Thank you everyone!
**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I'm getting a java error when I try to run an app that has both facebook and paypal sdk as dependencies. It works fine when I comment the facebook sdk dependency on gradle, but I need facebook login to work for my application too. Please help.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.12.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
}
```

The error message:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgLucasrTwowayviewTwowayview014Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic     (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 39.781 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Provide full error text from `Messages`

Comment: Try to enable multidex in gradle

Comment: I did and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What is in your "lib" directory -  `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` can have a jar with a conflicting class with facebook

Comment: I removed that line and replaced them with the following:
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.12.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any libraries in your libs folder --> Right Click > Add as library

Then delete this line > **compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')**

**OR**

It must have been a problem with the Java install. Remove all traces of Java and reinstall. Answer **here** [Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your Minimum SDK more or equal to API Level-15, check your project libs folder and make sure it should not have any 'Face Book' (.jar) files.

Comment: minSdkVersion 18 and there're no facebook jars in my libs folder

Answer (score 0):

if you have two classes or variables with the same name except in first caracter (for me one starts with a capital letter) this will cause the problem if you're using java 1.8