# how to fix java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 in android studio

Tags: android

My project in android studio in windows was working good but when i update SDK this error stoped my app:

Error:Execution failed for task ':Proj:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc2'

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    foss {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
 }

  sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
 }

 sourceSets.debug {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
 }

 sourceSets.release {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
 }

 sourceSets.foss {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
 }

 defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23  
 }
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
}
```

I cleaned and rebuild project, free my RAM and all ways in stackoverflow but they did not solve my problem.

Comment: plaese show the complete gradle file

Comment: there is a lot of things can be the reason of you problem, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1