# Android studio not working while gradle does not compile and has error

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have tried the ways of changing the extension, but it could not solve the problem too, is there any way else?

```
:app:mergeDebugResources

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library

:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

:app:generateDebugResources

:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig

:app:checkDebugManifest

:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

:app:compileDebugRenderscript

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library

:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, 

:app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, 

:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

:app:compileDebugAidl

AAPT err(Facade for 1614764273): libpng error: Not a PNG file

AAPT err(Facade for 1614764273): libpng error: Not a PNG file

:app:clean

:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library

:app:prepareDebugDependencies

:app:mergeDebugAssets

AAPT err(Facade for 1919759698): libpng error: Not a PNG file

AAPT err(Facade for 2070257548): libpng error: Not a PNG file

AAPT err(Facade for 246113197): libpng error: Not a PNG file

AAPT err(Facade for 974013731): libpng error: Not a PNG file

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

```
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps,

Cut the images and paste any where in the system and open each with the respective editor and save as the same but in PNG format and then copy and paste again to drawable folders.

Comment: The PNG problem solved, now I face this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1