# Execution failed when running app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am working on a program in Java Android with a log in system that communicates via webservice with a database. When i add the encryption algorithm and the necessary jars I get the following error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "andreea.example.com.mobileapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr177.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
}
```

[UPDATE] 
I have solved the previous issue, but i now get the following error:
(i have also added - multiDexEnabled true - in gradle)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/DrawableRes.class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because 65K and you need to enable multidex. But it's just a guess.

To understand the problem you can try build project from console by using

> gradle build --debug

or

> gradle build --info

after it you need to read or share output.