# app:dexDebug failed. Finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, mysql

After I added mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar as one of my libraries to my project I have been getting an error that says:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
Process'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have of course been looking at the similar questions on how to solve this here on stackoverflow but none of them seem to work for me. Some things I have tried include **cleaning the project**. This seemed like it solved the problem for most people in other threads, however it didn't do any difference for me.

I also added  **multiDexEnabled true** in the gradle file within the defaultConfig which didn't do any difference either.

I have made sure that I don't use my library twice.

Here is my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.myapplicationId"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

(myapplicationId is not the real applicationId).

All help is appreciated!

Comment: whats your gradle version ?

Comment: i used `mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar `

Comment: I'm using gradle version 2.4

Comment: Did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37542296/3111083?

Comment: okay , set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

Comment: @boking you can follow above link

Comment: Yes I have tried everything said in the above link. Do I just change the current classpath (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0') to the one you said or do I need to change some more if I do that? If I just change it I get a warning saying: Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in .../gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip