# Unable to run a new project on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android studio after creating a new project. if i run the project without doing anything  or i write some code also i m getting this error

**Error:Execution failed for task** `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug`.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

if i opend a alredy created projec  i can run in that.

Comment: What is you Build tools version number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please once change JDK with 1.8.* and clean project.It'll work.

If still get multidex error then need to add multidex as well in app.

Comment: Can you tell why minus ?

Comment: Once check about your question no one answering except these three.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)....the problem is with your java installation...you need to remove all traces of your java and jre then reinstall them from this [Official Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)...

Comment: don't give any suggestion otherwise #Aruna will disagree

Answer (score 0):

Please,clean your project first.
For this,
Go to Build->Clean Project