# Android Studio Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

I have recently changed the from JDK 1.7 to 1.8 for getting the `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0` for my app. It worked fine for a day and from the next day it was not building the app properly it's throwing this error while running the project [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi5NX.jpg)
take a look at my gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XXXXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 18
    versionName "XXXXX"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.4')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile files('libs/razorpay-android-0.13.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
...........
..........
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: please take a look at the updated question

Comment: You are passing an invalid jvm argument.

Answer (score 1):

this how I solved it :

1. go to environment variables
2. in system variables add :
3. New Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
4. New Variable Value: -Xmx512M

Restart Android studio

Comment: It worked for me but Value: -Xmx2048M had worked for me

Comment: thanx @Amr Alla

Comment: you can also increase memory in gradle.properties file in Android studio by setting org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you.

> File -> Settings -> Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)

Change the "**VM options**" to 
-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Please give a bit of a context before making people do changes to their Java virtual machine settings inside Android Studio.

Comment: there is no VM options in Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

In your log...

Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

**The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.**

So try to set the value of **javaMaxHeapSize "1g"** because it's depends on your maximum representable size which is given by your computer environment.

Or

Just remove these lines

```
dexOptions {
incremental true
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Hope this will help you.