# Android error to Generate Signed APK

Tags: android, apk, android-build

I am trying to `Build --> Generate Signed Apk`, and I am getting this error.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Can anyone help me out to this issue?

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: @Sagar hahaha clean and build is not only the solution exist in Android development world :) just kidding

Comment: @PareshMayani hahahaha. 90% of the build issues are either solved by clean & rebuild or invalidate cache :-D

Comment: hahah.. hello sagar, I tried this same many times.. but still same problem :(

Comment: have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1) ?

Comment: you mean this solution? **It must have been a problem with my Java install. I removed all traces of Java (C://program files/Java/jdk) and jre folders and reinstalled it from the official page and now it works fine.**

Comment: Yes. Check out that one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please remove Java completely (jdk and jre) and then try downloading Java from original web site and install again.

It should solve the problem.

Comment: Really? Did you try this?

Comment: yes..Just tried this.. but It didn't work my friend.

Comment: any other solution except this?