# Android Studio JRE process finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

With these dependencies present in build.gradle.

I am getting this error when i am trying to run the project

> Process 'command '/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

```
    /*CamerAFragment*/
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    //butterknife
    // implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //circle indicator
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    //google plus
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    /*Viper*/
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    // reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"
    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    // dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    //multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //new start
//    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
//    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    //new end

    //animationasdasd
    compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    //DrawablePageIndicator
    implementation 'com.augustopicciani.drawable_page_indicator:library:1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

   // AutoScrollView
    implementation('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'

    }

    //Cropper
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
/*AWS*/
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'

    /*//glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'*/

    //Country code
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.2'
    // implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.0.3'

    //Underscore
    implementation 'com.github.javadev:underscore:1.28'

    //pdf opener
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    //Crash
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'

    /*  // Check for v11.4.2 or higher
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'*/

    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    /*Custom Camera view*/
    implementation project(':Cameralibrary')

    /*App purchase */
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'

/*OCR demo Gradle starts from here */

//        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${versions.lifecycle}"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:${versions.lifecycle}"
    implementation "com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:${versions.relinker}"

    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${versions.leak_canary}"
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${versions.leak_canary}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.commit451:PhotoView:${versions.photoview}"
//        implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'

//butterknife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${versions.butterknife}"
//        kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${versions.butterknife}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${versions.butterknife}"
    //circle indicator
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'

    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.design}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.appcompat_v7}"

    //pdf shockwave
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.9.0'

//cat loader
    implementation 'com.roger.catloadinglibrary:catloadinglibrary:1.0.4'

//shimmer text
    compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
    /*End here */

//    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.2")

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Did this ever work (when the project started with less dependencies)? Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your help
any suggestion regarding my issue?

Comment: Can you answer the question I asked?

Comment: @cricket_007 
No
this never happens with less dependencies.

Comment: And that is the only error you get? Can you enable the gradle stacktrace options? Or go to the terminal, and do `./gradlew build`?

Comment: `firebase-crash:11.0.4` is quite dated (besides it is obsolete), compared to those `ml` libraries and support libraries also have mixed version numbers; it's a mess ...however, this should barely crash the JRE, which is the JVM on which the IDE runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Comment: @MartinZeitler i have updated the version of firebase-crash 11.0.4 to 16.2.1 but getting the same error.

Comment: you have one dependency as compile, rename it to implementation

Answer (score 0):

Your project includes too many dependencies, try remove them one by one and gradle sync until you find which one caused error.

Its a time consuming task, but should do if you can not ensure.

And you could try add this in build.gradle----android:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //enlarge heap size value.
}
```

Comment: @TechValens so you really need removing some libraries , hope lucky.

Comment: Actually, my code was working properly with libraries, a few hours ago I am getting this error.

Comment: @TechValens Invalidate cahe/restart android studio ,   or reboot machine.

Comment: did you change something a new drawable maybe. I had a similar problem when I changed my drawable and put the new one in drawables-v24 instead.