# I get java error when I want to build apk

Tags: java, android

For using the Line login in my app I read the Line API documentation and did exactly what was in the documentation.

Line documentation : https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/android-sdk/integrate-line-login/

When I wanted to build apk of my project I got this error :
`Process 'command 'C:\AndroidStudio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

I installed the latest version of Java and that didn't fix the problem.

## build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dir 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation(name:'line-sdk-5.0.0',ext:'aar')
    implementation('com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    api 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.10.5'
    runtimeOnly ('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:0.10.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

}
```

I read this ([Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)) and that didn't work either.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

P.s. my java installation folder is `C:/Program Files/java/jre1.8.0_191`